# In Eclipse - losing preferences when I create new workspace in windows

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

in windows,
   If i create new workspace preferences getting lose.

> - Installed JRE's
> - Grails
> - Code Collaberator. and others.

But it not happening in My Linux machine. Could i know what is the issue

I am using same version of eclipse, java in both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This should work the same on Linux and Windows. As a workaround, you can export the preferences from the first workspace and import in the other.

Also, when you switch to a workspace, there are copy options. But as far as I can see, this only allows to prevent copying the layout and working sets (which you usually don't want to copy). The standard preferences should always be copied.

Related articles:

- http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w

Comment: Preferences are only copied, if the new workspace is created through the Switch Workspace menu item and the copy settings are selected. Even then very few preferences are copied (I don't know why that is). The only official way to copy most useful, non-layout, preferences is through the export function, as Aaron mentions. Select Export All, to get most of the preferences. It depends on how plug-ins are codes as to whether preferences for them are exported and imported. Or you could try the solution that Aaron linked to.